# "One of the objects is not a path , cannot perform boolean operation" error when using division tool in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, tools

I want to cut the object below in Inkscape 0.92 :

[opengl.svg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sfkFcueS3SdpVuqfGB2UrXbEyXs9Yewd)

After converting it to path , I was unable to use the division tool because of the following error:

```
One of the objects is not a path  , cannot perform boolean operation
```

[image]

I also converted that black box into path but nothing special happened.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which specific object/objects are you trying to cut?  There are many. And which boolean operation are you trying to use?  Why are you trying to cut it up, what's your ultimate goal?  Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/136146/edit) and add some more details. Thanks.

Comment: @BillyKerr As I mentioned I want to use the "division tool" and I just wanted to take it to multiple pieces.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then user287001 has basically answered it, ungroup all your objects and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a 2 level group of quite simple paths. Every path can be accessed separately. You must ungroup the paths if you want to access them with the normal selection tool easily with no errors

If you must divide the paths do it separately or combine those which do not intersect. The big oval and O intersect and shouldn't be combined because it creates a hole.

Here the paths are recolored.

[image]

They can be accessed separately in the groups via the Objects panel or with the node tool.

Another possibility is to ungroup twice and then select all + make an union (Path > Union). The result is a single path (= a combined path). That can be easily divided with Path > Division. Here's a result of such attempt:

[image]